# Having problems with normalizing databases login

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli

I am new to normalizing databases and I am setting up a login page,

i have this code: and it doesnt work

```
                        $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql , $password);
                        $emailuser = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql , $emailuser);
                        $pwcheck = "
                        SELECT * FROM business AS p 
                        INNER JOIN user_business_data 
                        AS c ON p.id = c.id 
                        WHERE username='$emailuser' OR email='$emailuser'";
                        $resultcheck = mysqli_query($sql , $pwcheck);
                        $rowcheck = mysqli_fetch_array($resultcheck , MYSQLI_ASSOC);
                        $hash = $rowcheck['password'];
                        $hash_pwd = password_verify($password , $hash);
                        if ($hash_pwd != 0) {

                            $_SESSION['username'] = $rowcheck['username'];
                            $_SESSION['logged'] = true;
                            header("refresh:0;url=blablabla.php");

                        }
```

**NOTE I HAVE 2 DIFFERENT TABLES, business AND user_business_data, help**

Comment: you'll need to define "doesn't work"; any errors? checking for them?

Comment: What has that code to do with normalization?

Comment: No errors, I tried using error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1); but it didnt work

Comment: `mysqli_error($sql)` on the queries? I don't see that.

Comment: I didn't try doing that, ill try that

Comment: run that on the query then post your errors in your question, if any.

Comment: no errors i have no idea

Comment: what is the password column length then? that may be failing on you silently, and what does var_dump return?

Comment: hmmm right, ill try changing that! one second

Comment: works! Thanks :D I really didnt think about its length, @Fred-ii- haha!

Comment: I had a feeling that's what it was and have posted my answer below that you can mark off as solved. @guy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments; the password column's length is too short and you need to start over with a new hash.

The column should be 60+.

> *what is the password column length then? that may be failing on you **silently** – Fred -ii-*
>
> *works! Thanks :D I really didnt think about its length, @Fred-ii- haha! – guy*

As per the manual on `password_hash()`

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

> *Therefore, it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).*